# Delete cvs tag from deleted file (Eclipse CVS)?

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I tagged some files in a CVS project. Files were deleted and the project was retagged to the same version, with "move existing tag" option checked.

I expected that the deleted files would no longer be a part of this tag version, but they are. Is there a way to untag files that are no longer in project? Also, is there a way to do this automatically, so that when I choose to delete a file that's tagged, it gets both removed and untagged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tag isn't removed.  You'll have to cvs tag -d my_tag filename.  It is usually easiest to do it before removing the file:

i.e.

```
cvs tag -d my_tag my_file
rm my_file
cvs rm my_file
cvs ci -m "my file has been removed" myfile
```